# DAC noise floor vs resolution

Tags: dac

For an amplified DAC output, the noise floor is as following:

[image]

I want to move [this galvo mirror](https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/1676d5f1e1069735-A14FB9D8-B7D5-B777-CB00AA635A733384/GVS112-Manual.pdf) with the DAC. Which voltage parameter tells us what is the minimum increment can be sensed by an instrument? Mean, rms or peak to peak? And how can I estimate roughly the minimum movement of the galvo?

Comment: This looks like noise of whatever ADC you use to measure.

Comment: how many bit DAC? what is the full scale voltage? was the input fed with a constant value?

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @KevinWhite They keep changing here is updated one hope you can access it before they change https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/4405a126b53111ad-1C04EBD1-971A-394B-915C7873A5F64538/GVS112-Manual.pdf Otherwise you can see it by googling GVS112-Manual.pdf

Comment: @GNZ - I managed to get it and the bandwidth is about 130Hz so the only noise you need to consider is in the DC-130Hz region. You will need to find out the rise in that region from the DAC apart from 1/f noise it is probably pretty small and the LSB increment may be the limit rather than noise. You also need to define what you mean by "Minimum increment".